# ¿Como obtener datos que están almacenados en tres tablas con una condicional?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

necesito hacer una consulta a una base de datos mysql donde tengo que obtener unos datos que se encuentran en tres tablas, el problema es que tengo que hacer una condicional y no he logrado ningún resultado hasta el momento.

ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es un simple ejemplo, que creo puede ayudar a entender la consulta.
La consulta lo que me pide es los siguiente:

Indicar el **nombre del usuario** que tenga un **valor de fruta en Cero** y tenga como **Acción: “Mirar”**, si se dan cuenta en la tabla valores_de_fruta se repiten los nombres de las frutas, por lo que hay que escoger **solo el último registro**, lo mismo pasa con la tabla Accion_de_comprar, se repiten los id de usuario, pero se escoge solo el último registro.

Un resultado de ejemplo seria el siguiente:

**Juan – Manzana – mirar**

Espero me puedan ayudar con esta consulta, estoy aprendiendo sql y estas consultas complejas se no he logrado entender aún.

Gracias.

Comment: En las consultas solo es necesario anteponer el nombre de la tabla si puede crear ambiguedades. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

esto deberia de hacer lo que quieres:

```
SELECT USUARIOS.NOMBRE,Valores_de_Frutas.Nombre_de_fruta,Acción_de_compra.accion 
    FROM USUARIOS, Valores_de_Frutas,Acción_de_compra 
    WHERE USUARIOS.ID = Valores_de_Frutas.Usuario_id 
    AND USUARIOS.ID = Acción_de_compra.Usuario_id
    AND  Valores_de_Frutas.Valor = 0
    AND  Acción_de_compra.accion = 'mirar'
    GROUP BY USUARIOS.NOMBRE,Valores_de_Frutas.Nombre_de_fruta,Acción_de_compra.accion;
```

Saludos.

Asi tambien lo puedes hacer:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, Nombre_de_fruta, accion 
        FROM USUARIOS 
        INNER JOIN Valores_de_Frutas ON  USUARIOS.ID = Valores_de_Frutas.Usuario_id AND Valor = 0
        INNER JOIN Acción_de_compra ON USUARIOS.ID = Acción_de_compra.Usuario_id AND  accion = 'mirar'
        GROUP BY NOMBRE, Nombre_de_fruta, accion;
```

Comment: Gracias, fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Sin decir que la anterior este mala, es recomendable hacer uso de los `INNER JOIN` que une las tablas por sus campos en comun y en cuestiones de rendimiento (cuando la consulta es muy grande se demora menos), ademas el uso de los alias `AS` para que la consulta sea legible y menos extensa, seria asi:

```
SELECT us.NOMBRE, vf.Nombre_de_fruta, ac.accion 
        FROM USUARIOS AS us  
   //con esto se unen las tablas
        INNER JOIN Valores_de_Frutas AS vf ON  us.ID = vf.Usuario_id 
        INNER JOIN Acción_de_compra AS ac ON us.ID = ac.Usuario_id
   //el whre libre para la condicion normal
        WHERE  vf.Valor = 0  AND  ac.accion = 'mirar'
   //y el agrupamiento de campos en el caso que sean varias
        GROUP BY us.NOMBRE, vf.Nombre_de_fruta, ac.accion
```

las dos hacen lo mismo, ya tu miraras cual se te hace mas facil de entender y asimilar en el proceso... exitos

Comment: Ok, bro. como tu digas no tengo problema con eso, esa es la enseñanza y experiencia que ha adquirido al comparar los dos tipos de connsultas, pero si tu lo estas seguro de ellos, te agradezco haberme hecho saber. Saludos

Comment: Ok bro, no hay el por que de la arrogancia, dejalo asi la tuya es mucho mejor y tu sabes mucho mas. Me disculpo si te ofendi en algo @SantiagoCeladaGonzalez ,,, ReNiceCode...